# Finding records between a given date range in sql with a varchar column

Tags: c#, sql, string, date

I have the following problem. I wrote a query to get the date of an order in c#:

```
QueryDate = string.Format("(Order.Begin>= '{0}' and Order.End<= '{1}')", BeginDate, EndDate);
```

The problem is my SQL Server table columns, 'Begin' and 'End', are varchar columns and I want to keep them this way. They are saved as '12-4-2012' for example.

Now I want to get the dates between say '12-4-2012' and '19-4-2012'. But the result is everything between '12' and '19' with the first 2 digits. So the results also include '14-8-2011' for example.

Is there a way retrieve only the dates between '12-4-2012' and '19-4-2012' with a string column?

Comment: That's a very very bad design. There is no easy way to do it without using a complex conversion of you strings that cripples the optimization engine of SqlServer

Comment: Storing dates as strings is a very bad design. What is 12-4, April 12 or December 4? Constructing the SQL string like this is also begging for SQL injection attacks

Comment: April 12. The user is using a DateTimePicker and the default format is dd-MM-yyyy and this is being coverted into a string. And the program is internal. It can't be executed from our server unless you log in into our domain

Comment: The only "default" date format in SQL is YYYYMMDD. Anything else requires an assumption that can easily fail, eg. if you deploy to a database with US collation

Comment: All the answers were almost the same but they did helped. Thanks everybody. We will try to change the design when we get the chance to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can convert the Begin and Order columns into DateTime format something like this:

`QueryDate = string.Format("(convert(datetime, Order.Begin, 105) >= @startdate and convert(datetime, Order.End, 105)<= @enddate;"`

And then add he @startdate, and @enddae parameters...

Answer (score 1):

Use Parameters and encapsulate you column names with square brackets
Then supposing your input strings are valid date you could do:

```
DateTime dStart = DateTime.ParseExact(BeginDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CurrentCulture.CultureInfo); 
DateTime dEnd = DateTime.ParseExact(EndDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CurrentCulture.CultureInfo); 

string QueryDate = "SELECT * FROM Order " + 
                   "WHERE CONVERT('smalldatetime', [Begin], 105) >= @start " + 
                   "AND CONVERT('smalldatetime', [End], 105) <= @end";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(QueryDate, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", dStart);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", dEnd);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be a possibility?

```
string.Format("(convert(datetime, Order.Begin, 105)>= convert(datetime, '{0}', 105) and convert(datetime, Order.End, 105)<= convert(datetime, '{1}', 105))", BeginDate, EndDate);
```